# SAS input file description

Tags: sas, mainframe

Below is the code. Where `AFILE` is the input file. Nowhere in the SAS code am finding the column description for this file.

How can I find the description of the input file columns?

Will `BFILE` hold all the columns that are in `AFILE`?

Here AFILE is the `DDNAME` of dataset from `JCL`,  `BFILE` is a SAS dataset

```
PROC SORT DATA=AFILE.BFILE OUT=BFILE;
BY COMPANY;
RUN;
```

Comment: Is FILE a SAS dataset or a raw file?

Comment: if Afile or Bfile both are sas datasets, then you can use proc contents to see what is inside the datasets. ---- proc contents data=afile; run;

Comment: AFILE is not a data file. It's a LIBREF.  What this is doing is to sort AFILE.BFILE into WORK.BFILE.  The libref, in batch, is //AFILE DD ...  In SAS Enterprise edition its  mapped to a directory.  Look at documentation for LIBREF and LIBNAME.